Did Tunisia's president return €150 million paid by the EU as part of a “cash for migration control” deal?
According to The Telegraph, (alleged) EU papers leaked by Hungary show that:

Kais Saied, [Tunisia's] authoritarian president, has returned €150 million paid by the EU as part of a “cash for migration control” deal.
He described the sum as “derisory”, two months after the pact was agreed in July 2023.

But The Guardian says something rather different:

The EU will be unable to claw back any of the €150m (£125m) paid to Tunisia despite the money being increasingly linked to human rights violations, including allegations that sums went to security forces who raped migrant women.

So it seems like Tunisia kept the money, unless it's a different €150m?

This article of "Le Monde" (published end December 2023) says that :

At the beginning of October, a dispute broke out between Brussels and
Tunis, which had returned an aid of 60 million euros to the EU, an
unprecedented approach for a partner country, according to Brussels.
The Tunisian President, Kaïs Saïed, said he rejected the EU's
"charity" and assured that the sum had been paid "without the Tunisian
authorities having been informed in advance", denouncing an "attack on
dignity" of his country.
The funds were in reality planned as part of a post-Covid recovery aid
program, unrelated to the July protocol, which also includes aid of
105 million euros to Tunisia to fight against irregular immigration.

N.B.: The 150 millions euros corresponds to July 2023 partnership agrreement between Tunisia and EU, and includes an amount of 105 million euros related to migration problem.
